# Getting errors running mount on Amazon Linux after installing s3fs (`MOUNT_2.22' not found required by mount)

Tags: linux, fuse, s3fs

Followed [these instructions to install s3fs on Amazon Linux](http://www.logikdev.com/2012/04/03/install-s3fs-on-amazon-clouds/).

It worked fine on one of my systems, however on a different system (following the same instructions) I am getting the following errors when running /bin/mount

```
[root@ip-10-99-1-35 lib64]# mount
mount: /lib64/libmount.so.1: version `MOUNT_2.21' not found (required by mount)
mount: /lib64/libmount.so.1: version `MOUNT_2.22' not found (required by mount)
mount: /lib64/libmount.so.1: version `MOUNT_2.20' not found (required by mount)
```

EDIT: I should mention, it was only getting one of the errors above (the 2.20), however, I tried installing the util-linux source package for versions v2.21, and v2.22 when I started running into problems.

Running ldd on mount, I get this

```
[root@ip-10-99-1-35 lib64]# ldd /bin/mount
/bin/mount: /lib64/libmount.so.1: version `MOUNT_2.21' not found (required by /bin/mount)
/bin/mount: /lib64/libmount.so.1: version `MOUNT_2.22' not found (required by /bin/mount)
/bin/mount: /lib64/libmount.so.1: version `MOUNT_2.20' not found (required by /bin/mount)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff507ff000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib64/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f5e9331a000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f5e930f9000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f5e92ef4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5e92b62000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5e93533000)
```

The appropriate files in /lib64

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Jul 30 15:25 /lib64/libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  61728 Jul 28  2011 /lib64/libmount.so.1.1.0
```

Distro Info

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-99-1-35 ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.03
Kernel \r on an \m

[ec2-user@ip-10-99-1-35 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-99-1-35 3.2.20-1.29.6.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 12 01:19:28 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: And which distribution is this?

Comment: Its Amazon Linux, I will put the uname/issue above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem be reinstalling the util-linux package.

```
yum reinstall util-linux
```